# How to hide or not send input name if empty? php

Tags: php, forms, field

I have a PHP form. Is it possible to not send/hide tag name="Field2" of an input text field, if its "value" is empty?
Code:

```
<form action="searchresult.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="Field1">
<input type="text" name="Field2">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The result should be:

If the field `name="Field2`" is empty: searchresult.php?Field1=value

If the field `name="Field2"` is not empty: searchresult.php?Field1=value&Field2=value

Comment: You can prevent formdefaults with javascript on button (submit) click. Then remove the Field2, and then submit the form

Comment: @hoi: the empty params are okay in URL. If you want to remove them, just test which are set and redirect to a _correct_ URL.

Comment: you can check it in php :if($_POST['field2_']==''

Comment: `if(empty($_POST['var'])){...}` yep.

Comment: You can catch post values for field1,field2 and check for empty,then apply conditions on it and redirect accordingly..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    $(".btnSubmit").on("click", function(){
        var content = $.trim($("#input").val());
        if(content == '' || content == null){
            $("#input").removeAttr( "name" );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yuck -- a code-only answer.  Saw this answer in the Review queue.  Answers without explanation are low value on SO because they do very little to educate the OP or future readers.  If this answer is correct (I didn't check) please edit it to explain why it is a good solution and what it does.  Otherwise please delete.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with jQuery.
You must catch the `submit` and check if there are any empty fields, and remove them. This will redirect you to given url without any empty fields in URL

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').submit(function () {
        var newurl = $(this).find(":input").filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.value).length > 0
        }).serialize();
        window.location($('#form').attr('action') + '?' + newurl );
        return false;
    });
});
```